# Multiple repositories in Nexus Repository Manager when publishing one project

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I have been making several hundreds of releases in the exact same way without any problems. Recently I started getting multiple repositories in the staging are of Nexus Repository Manager, when publishing a single project.

I cannot publish the release, because half of it is in one repository and the other half is in the other repository making each repository incomplete. See this screenshot where 2 repositories, sebjurr, has been created for one single release of one single project.

[image: multiple repositories, sebjurr]

Here is what I've been doing for years.
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-lib/blob/1.33/build.gradle
I've done it with ./gradlew release

Here is a recent attempt where I tried without plugins.
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-lib/blob/feature/trying-release-without-plugins/build.gradle
I've done a ./gradlew build and a ./gradlew uploadArchives

Comment: I'm switching to Bintray instead to avoid this problem. https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin

Comment: If you're still having issue, sounds like a question for https://issues.sonatype.org/projects/OSSRH/ not a general nexus question.  If you're having this problem outside of oss.sonatype.org, I think we'd need to see logs.